# Type cast child to grandparent class

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, casting, deque

Current code:

```cpp
class A { 
    // Abstract class
    ... 
};

class B : public A { 
    // Concrete class
    ... 
};

class C : public B { 
    // Concrete class
    ... 
};

class D : public C { 
    // Abstract class
    ... 
};

class E : public A {
    // Concrete class
private:
    std::deque< std::shared_ptr<A> > m_deque;

public:
    E& operator+=( std::shared_ptr<D> temp ) {
        m_deque.push_front( temp );
        ...
    }
    ...
};
```

When trying to overload the `+=` operator I want to push the parameter `temp` into the deque `m_deque`. The problem is that the types don't match up. How do I push `temp` into the deque `m_deque`?

I was trying to type cast `temp`, but I'm not sure how to type cast to a grandparent class.

Comment: You're not casting to a grandparent class; `std::shared_ptr<A>` is not a grandparent of `std::shared_ptr<D>`.

Comment: I have no problems compiling this in GCC: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b74ea6bbbb8da38. It also compiles fine in MSVC++. And it should compile as is, there's no need to "type cast" anything. What compiler are you using? What error message are you getting?

Comment: @immibis: Yet `std::shared_ptr<D>` is implicitly convertible to `std::shared_ptr<A>`, meaning that the code should compile.

Comment: @AnT I am using Xcode 6, which uses Apple LLVM 6. The error message I am receiving is: No matching member function for call to 'push_front'. That's why I thought that I needed to type cast. Since I am trying to push a `D` type pointer into a deque of `A` type pointers.

Comment: @Amous: There's no need for any casts here. The code should compile as is. If the code you posted above is accurate, then there must be some issue with the implementation you are using. You might try doing `std::shared_ptr<A> p = temp; m_deque.push_front(p);` and see what happens.

Comment: @AnT I was trying that earlier, but it gave another error: `No viable conversion from 'shared_ptr<class D>' to 'shared_ptr<class A>'`. When I try `std::shared_ptr<A> p; m_deque.push_front(p);` it checks out, which is why I still think it may be a type problem...

Comment: I can't reproduce this on any clang/libc++ version on wandbox. Please post the full error message for `std::shared_ptr<A> p = temp;`, including the notes enumerating the candidate functions.

Comment: Ah the problem was in one of the included header files! Thanks for everyones help!